# Batch files: Outputting into txt file

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I'm trying to output the `dir c:/[x:x` etc list into a text file as well with the following code `DIR >"Input Data".txt`

The above works but it doesn't display exactly what is output onto command prompt screen. It includes all files and directories in the root of c: drive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
CD  c:\
DIR  C:/D/A:H-D/L
ECHO.
DIR  >"Input Data".txt
ECHO.
MOVE c:/"Input Data".txt c:/"My Batch Script File Assignment"/"Input"/
```

Comment: Can you post the entire line you are putting in? As well, what OS you are using?

Comment: CD  c:\
DIR  C:/D/A:H-D/L
DIR  >"Input Data".txt

Comment: windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Click on the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/470182/edit) button and add that information to the question

Comment: I put it in the main part so it's easier to read :)

Comment: It's still outputting a list of all 7 files and 10 directories in the root of c:

Comment: Even when trying `DIR C: /D /A:H-D /L > "Input Data.txt"`? This command is working for me as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do know that Windows 7 uses `\` instead of `/` like *nix operating systems?
2. Try putting a space between each switch in line 2 (i.e. `DIR C: /D /A:H-D /L`)
3. The DIR command two lines down that pipes out to the file is just using the default `DIR`, which includes non-hidden non-system files and folders in the current folder. Add the `>"Input Data".txt` after the command in line 2

Comment: Really? I was wondering what the difference was between / and \ so thanks! So just to be clear; while working on windows 7 I have to use /? I'll try out your suggestion now :)

Comment: On Windows, `/` means a switch or argument; `\ ` is a path seperator

Comment: Progress! It's outputting hidden files only into the txt file, it's not displaying on the cmd window but that can be fixed with adding another DIR  C: /D /A:H-D /L above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. If it solves your problem, feel free to upvote once you get 15 rep:)